# How to test JavaScript memory usage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, google-chrome-devtools, profiling

I currently have some code that I would like to test the memory usage of to see how much memory a large Map actually takes up. I am just unsure how I should go about this? I heard Google Chrome memory profiling works, but I am unsure how to test a specific piece of code rather than the current website I am on.

The code I am trying to test the memory consumption of is the following:

```
const map = new Map();

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    map.set(i, {
        test1: "123a6ad980b05dwgd8b1f44b52df09448f",
        test2: 1
    });
}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: Try measuring `performance.memory` before and after.